# Switch case in javascript in a function for GTM

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, google-tag-manager

I need to create a Google Tag Manager Javascript function that would return a label (group label) from a var entry that is a number (id of the group)
I created this function but it doesn't work (returns undefined)
I'm really new with Javascript so I don't understand what is wrong.

```
function client_group_name(id_client_group) {
var id_client_group = {{CONTEXT - User / Group / ID Default Group}}; //this is my GTM variable , numeric could take value 3, 5, 6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10 ,11  
switch(id_client_group) {
    case "3" :
        value = "B2C";
        break;
    case "5" :
        value = 'B2B Entreprises';
        break;
    case "6": case "7": case "8": case "9": case "10": case "11":
        value = 'B2B Café, Hôtel, Restaurant - CHR'
        break;
  }
return value;  
}
```

Google tag Manager Javascript functions need a function () and return statements to work.
Thanks for your help.
Best regards.

Comment: Is there an error in your console? You have `id_client_group` as a parameter, and then again as a variable, which doesn't look to be syntactically correct. What is `id_client_group` just before your switch statement?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to name your functions or to pass vars into them. Just get rid of the quotes around the case numbers since the type won't match.

While JS is certainly able to solve this issue, solving it with JS is an overkill. All you need here is a simple regex table (rLUT). Or just a simple Look up Table, but rLUT will be a more elegant solution.

This is how it should be set up, approximately:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wasn't thinking about this solution. Works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what `var id_client_group = ...` is supposed to mean. However,  it's *shadowing* the function argument with the same name.

Inside the `case`'s you've defined, the script creates a *global variable* called `value`. You should declare that variable first inside you function. But then, since you can utilize the fact that a `return` inside a `switch-case` allows for an early exit, just return the label you need.

Additionally, you mention that `id_client_group` is a `Number`, but your `switch-case` statement checks agains `String` values. Therefor I suggest:

1. Change `case "3":` and similar to `case 3:`
2. Add a `default:` case to your `switch-case` statement, because if `id_client_group` is neither `3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10` or `11`, the `value` variable is - of course - `undefined` since it's not even created.

For example:

```js
function client_group_name(id_client_group) {
  switch(id_client_group) {
    case 3:
        return "B2C";
    case 5:
        return 'B2B Entreprises';
    case 6: 
    case 7: 
    case 8: 
    case 9: 
    case 10: 
    case 11:
        return 'B2B Café, Hôtel, Restaurant - CHR';
    default:
      return 'Unknown';
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't name functions or pass variables into them in GTM CJS variables. Var is necessary there. Passing an arg is not.